# Odd columns division in css display:grid property. Making last 2 columns have the 50% each width when the columns are odd in count

Tags: css

I want to add grid-column: span 3.5; i dont know how it is possible or it is or not. Can anyonw help please ?

7 columns in a row needed

[image]

this is i have got so far. I just can't divide the last column

[image]

I cannot add any other column I just want to make this code work.

```
.skills ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, auto);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

ul li:nth-child(15), .skills ul li:nth-child(16) {
  grid-column: span 3; // I tried making it 3.5 but didn't worked.
}
```

Comment: You want the last two items to be centered ?

Comment: You can't. Grid items cannot span half a column. What you can do is double the number of columns but you still can't target the last row of a grid.

Comment: Yes boss @ZohirSalak

Comment: Are you sure @Paulie_D ? Isn't there anyway to give width individually for the last two columns, ignoring the width of other sibling elements ?

Comment: Nope. What you really want here is flexbox not css-grid

Comment: I know i can do it with flexbox but i wanted to do that with display: grid; So I guess there no way to do that with grid except the way Zohir Salak did.. Do you agree with that trick ?